# check for null fields in json python

Tags: python

A very naive question but is there a robust or better way to do following.
Say it has nothing to do with json actually.

let say I have list (reading from file)

```
string_list = [ "foo",1,None, "null","[]","bar"]
```

Now, `null and []` are essentially equivalent of null but different data structures have different interpretation of "None"?? right?

So rather than me writing a regex for all these rules.. is there a better way to convert "null","[]" etc to None.. ??

Thanks

Comment: That's a list, not a string.

Comment: My bad.. originally i thought of posting what i was facing.. (reading json strings in file with such fields).. but then realized that a simple list with such values will also explain the issue

Comment: It'd be better to show us a sample of the JSON than to show how you'd represent it in python.  Considering that `null` and `[]` are both valid in JSON, and that things like `len([])` works while `len(None)` does not, flattening all instances of empty lists to `None` might not be the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a set of values that should be replaced with `None` and use list comprehension to "replace" them:

```
>>> string_list = [ "foo",1,None, "null","[]","bar"]
>>> none_items = {"null", "[]"}  # or set(("null", "[]"))
>>> [None if item in none_items else item for item in string_list]
['foo', 1, None, None, None, 'bar']
```

Or, use `map()`:

```
>>> map(lambda x: None if x in none_items else x, string_list)
['foo', 1, None, None, None, 'bar']
```

Using `set` because of O(1) lookups.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
string_list = [ "foo",1,None, "null","[]","bar"]
nones = [ "null", "[]" ]
print([None if s in nones else s for s in string_list])
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You shouldn't be converting anything to None.

2) The first thing you want to do is convert to json. The json module will convert null to None, so you don't have to worry about null.  And empty json strings, arrays, and objects, will be converted to empty python strings, lists, and dicts, so you won't be dealing with strings at all.

3) Then if you want to filter out the empty objects, you can do things like this:

```
import json

my_data = json.loads("""
    [
        "hello", 
        "", 
        [], 
        {}, 
        [1, 2, 3], 
        {"a": 1, "b": 2}
    ] 
""")

print(my_data)
print([x for x in my_data if x])

--output:--
['hello', '', [], {}, [1, 2, 3], {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
['hello', [1, 2, 3], {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Empty objects(including 0) evaluate to False.